# Apache Kafka: large retention time vs. fast read of last value

Tags: apache-kafka

Dear Apache Kafka friends,

I have a use case for which I am looking for an elegant solution:

Data is published in a Kafka-Topic at a relatively high rate. There are two competing requirements

- all records should be kept for 7 days (which is configured by *min.compaction.lag*)
- applications should read the "last status" from the topic during their initialization phase

LogCompaction is enabled in order for the "last state" to be available in the topic.
Now comes the problem. If an application wants to initialize itself from the topic, it has to read a lot of records to get the last state for all keys (the entire topic content must be processed). But this is not performant possible with the amount of records.

**Idea**

A streaming process streams the data of the topic into a corresponding *ShortTerm* topic which has a much shorter *min.compaction.lag* time (1 hour). The applications initialize themselves from this topic.

**Risk**

The streaming process is a potential source of errors. If it temporarily fails, the applications will no longer receive the latest status.

**My Question**

Are there any other possible solutions to satisfy the two requirements. Did I maybe miss a Kafa concept that helps to handle these competing requirements?

Any contribution is welcome. Thank you all.

Comment: Are you using `min.compaction.lag` config to get "7 days of data"? -- Also, for the short term topic, why do you say you use 1 hour retention: should this short term topic not be fully compacted -- otherwise you might lose initial state?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Yes I use `min.compaction.lag`. I use 1 hour because the amount of data is OK to be processed. I do not expect to loose any _latest key_ data. As far as I know keeping of the last key is guaranteed and independent from the _min.comaction.lag_. And I always expect dirty messages; not sure what you mean by 'fully compacted'

Comment: `I do not expect to loose any data.` -- but you don't have a guarantee. By "fully compacted" I mean to just use log compaction (no `min.compaction.lag`); of course, there  is always the non-compacted active-segment, but if you reduce the segment size and segment roll interval (or `max.compaction.lag`) you should get close to get a "fully compacted" topic (ie, with no duplicate keys).

Comment: `The streaming process is a potential source of errors. If it temporarily fails, the applications will no longer receive the latest status.` -- Why would this be a risk? You only use the "short term" topic to bootstrap, right?

Comment: The _ShortTerm_ topic would probably be used for bootstrap and also to receive all other data. Only reading it to bootstrap and then switching to the large topic to see if there is something new will not give me a benefit I think.

Comment: You say I do not have a guarantee to loose data. What do you mean by this? I have the guarantee in mind that at least the last record with a given key is provided in the topic. That would be OK for me. Loosing dirty records is OK. There are not relevant in the bootstrap phase and keeping them available at least 1 hour will also be enough to use the ShortTerm topic for further data subscription after the bootstrap phase.

Comment: `will not give me a benefit I think` -- well, I think it does, because you don't depend on the "copy job" any longer, ie, makes you robust if it fails.

Comment: `I have the guarantee in mind that at least the last record with a given key is provided in the topic.` -- There is no guarantee for this: if a key is not updated or 1 hour, it would get truncated from the topic.

Comment: Would love to chat about this but I have to leave now. Did not expect that quick reaction. Last thing. If the applicatiion switches from the ShotTerm topic to the "regular" one for subscription it has to read the missed records in the regular topic as well. But maybe not from the beginning. That is a fair point.

The ShortTerm Topic is of course also log compacted. If there is no guarantee that the last state is persisted - the log compaction concept would make no sense for me.

Comment: If the "short term" topic is compacted, then there is no "retention time" that you mentioned in the question (because you mentioned retention time, I assumed you want to use a non-compacted topic...). Good that we could clear this miss-understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a strict guarantee how frequently each key will be updated, you cannot do anything else as you proposed.

To avoid the risk that the downstream app does not get new updates (because the data replication jobs stalls), I would recommend to only bootstrap an app from the short term topic, and let it consume from the original topic afterwards. To not miss any updates, you can sync the switch over as follows:

1. On app startup, get the replication job's committed offsets from the original topic.
2. Get the short term topic's current end-offsets (because the replication job will continue to write data, you just need a fixed stopping point).
3. Consume the short term topic from beginning to the captured end offsets.
4. Resume consuming from the original topic using the captured committed offsets (from step 1) as start point.

This way, you might read some messages twice, but you won't lose any updates.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It doesn't make things any easier (for the consumer), but at least I haven't overlooked any concept that would support it even better.

Comment: It seems that we go with the `ShortTerm -> LongTerm` direction solution. The consumer do not need to change their bootstrap process in this case (they only work with the `ShortTerm` topic); the risk is to loose data if streaming to the `LongTerm` topic fails for some time; but since it is a Kafka2Kafka process, we believe it runs sufficiently stable

Answer (score 0):

To me, the two requirements you have mentioned together with the requirement for new consumers are not competing. In fact, I do not see any reason why you should keep a message of an outdated key in your topic for 7 days, because

- **New** consumers are only interested in the latest message of a key.
- **Already existing** consumers will have processed the message within 1 hour (as taken from your comments).

Therefore, my understanding is that your requirement "all records should be kept for 7 days" can be replaced by "each consumer should have enough time to consume the message & the latest message for each key should be kept for 7 days".

Please correct me if I am wrong and explain which consumer actually *does* need "all records for 7 days".

If that is the case you could do the following:

1. Enable log compaction as well as time-based retention to 7 days for this topic
2. Fine-tune the compaction frequency to be very *eager*, meaning to keep as little as possible outdated messages for a key.
3. Set min.compaction.lag to 1 hour such that all consumers have the chance to keep up.

That way, new consumers will read (almost) only the latest message for each key. If that is not performant enough, you can try increasing the partitions and consumer threads of your consumer groups.

Comment: The requirement to have all data available for at least 7 days is due to the fact that the data must be completely transferred to another system (archive). This system may not be available for several days.
So there are two types of clients. Those who are only interested in current data and those who need all data (with a 7-day buffer).

Comment: Would it be an option that the producer sends the identical data to two topics each serving different kind of clients?

Comment: Or even better: Have a dedicated, very simple streaming job that consumes the original topic and copy pasting the messages into a dedicated archive log.

Comment: producer sending to two topics would be an option yes

Comment: I would not recommend "double" writes... (except you use transactions). Otherwise, a record might end up in one topic but not in the other -- also, record order might be different.

Comment: Copy the data from the original topic to an "archive" log, it the same idea, just different direction :)

Comment: Yes, I admit, double writes are not a good thing @Matthias. About the different direction, to me it just feels cleaner to not have the responsibility in each "non-archive" application to switch topic consumption and seek to different offsets at beginning. From an operational point of view, this does not seem very "clean" :)

Comment: That's a fair point -- for the downstream consumer, reversing the "replication direction" is easier!

Comment: It seems that we go with the `ShortTerm -> LongTerm` direction solution. The consumer do not need to change their bootstrap process in this case (they only work with the `ShortTerm` topic); the risk is to loose data if streaming to the `LongTerm` topic fails for some time; but since it is a Kafka2Kafka process, we believe it runs sufficiently stable